# Handling HTML characters in web scraped html using Python BS4

Tags: python

This might be a duplicate question, but unable to find any answers searching through stackoverflow..

Scraped some html files from the web, but they contain special characters like '>', '<' in the text and BeautifulSoup is unable to handle it and throwing BeautifulSoup.find erratic. Is there a way to escape the text before using BeautifulSoup to parse the html?

EDIT:
Thought this is generic enough, but adding html with issue:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Title</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<hr align=left width=75%>
<dl><h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>
<dd><a href="./ref.pl?R1"><b>R1</b></a>
<i><b>PP</b></i>:
<a href="./refs.pl?R2">R2</a>
<dl>
<dd>
 Text1 <a href="./refs.pl?T1">T1</a>
; Text2 <a href="./refs.pl?T1">T1</a>
<i>value<=500</i> <a href="./refs.pl?+T2">T2</a>
; Text3 <a href="./refs.pl?T3">T3</a>
</dl>
Sat Feb  14 23:36:59 EST 2016
<p></body></html>
```

Trying to collect all text values, calling dd = soup.find('dd') and parsing dd.contents misses out value<=500 and Text3..

Comment: can you be a bit more specific like provide us the code and or the site you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but is there a easier way to handle it directly with BeautifulSoup?

```
from tidylib import tidy_document
doc, errors = tidy_document(htmlfile.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "lxml")
```

Now the HTML document has `<i>value&lt;=500</i>`, and this helps `BeautifulSoup.find` from behaving erratically.

Calling `dd = soup.find('dd')` and parsing `dd.contents` now provides `value<=500` and `Text3`.

Comment: Thanks @jwodder, appreciate it. new joinee still working my way around